# Google Places API - loading place types onclick

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm loading the 'school' place type into a map and want to be able to load in another place type on click of a link, as shown in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aboother/ke8h48w2/8/

So on click of the link I call my map function and pass in the type, eg:

```
initializePropertyMap('train_station');
```

This works well, but when I click either the 'show schools' or 'show train stations' link, the number of places returned gets less and less each time. E.g. if you click the 'show schools' link repetitively, the schools returned are reduced each time. Does anyone know why this may be?

---

Comment: Aren’t you resetting the `count` in the `for` loop every time because `var count = 0;` is _inside_ the `for` loop?

Comment: Also, the executing brackets `()` in the `addDomListener` should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are exceeding the usage limits of the Google maps API. After the if statement

```
if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
```

add an else statement, and log the failed requests. You will find the status returned is `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

[See here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Looks like I need to come up with a better way of showing/hiding the places